# Component not rendering with ReactJS and React Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-router

Building a web app using Meteor and React, and I'm trying to render two views within React, and the index component won't render... unsure why. The 'Two' component does. Here is my routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import { Index } from '../../ui/components/index.jsx';
import { Two } from '../../ui/pages/two.jsx';

Meteor.startup( () => {
  render( 
    <Router history={ browserHistory }>
       <Route path="/" component={ Index } />
       <Route path="/two" component={ Two } />
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById( 'react-root' ) 
  );
});
```

Index.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
        <Index className="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Todo List</h1>
            </header>
        </Index>
        ); 
    }
}
```

Two.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Two = () => <h3>Two</h3>;
```

What's going on? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be rendering Index inside Index component.

this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
        <Index className="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Todo List</h1>
            </header>
        </Index>
        ); 
    }
}
```

should be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
        <div className="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Todo List</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        ); 
    }
}
```

In addition as you are exporting `Index` as the default export, you should use

```
import Index from '../../ui/components/index.jsx';
```

or

```
import {default as Index} from "../../ui/components/index.jsx"
```

instead of using explicit named export `import { Index } ..`

Comment: that doesn't work... @QoP is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @girlrockingguna You are exporting `Index` as the default export, so you should do `import Index from "../../ui/components/index.jsx"` instead of `import {Index} from "../../ui/components/index.jsx"` (or `import`{default as Index} ..)` together with QoP said :)